# Upgrade to Windows 8 after downgrade to 7 (through downgrade rights)

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I received a Thinkpad from work that has Windows 7 Pro installed on it through the downgrade rights on Windows 8, but I'd actually like to upgrade it *back* to Windows 8. I assume it has the installation keys embedded in the BIOS somewhere, as there isn't a key on the case itself. I've tried the [Windows upgrade asssistant](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/upgrade-from-windows-7-tutorial), but it still askes me to order a copy.

I assume if I were to download the Windows 8 installer and run it manually, it would detect the embedded key and activate normally, but I am not certain. Is there an easy way to detect what the embedded product keys are valid for?

Comment: Since Windows 8 Enterprise cannot be downgraded to Windows 7 the license is either for Windows 8 or Windows 8  Professional.  You won't be able to download the installation media through the tool, those are only good for retail keys, and you have an OEM key.  You are correct the key will automatically be detected.

Comment: There may be a recovery partition on that laptop that contains W8.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can go there to create an installation media (usb or dvd)
the installation will not ask for a key since the win 8 key is in the bios
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
www.lenovo.com/lenovorecovery
Register your laptop and you'll receive a dvd/usb with the upgrade in two weeks.
Only 1 per device allowed.

Comment: This offer only applies to products purchased during a certain time period. From the site indicated in answer "You must have received a Lenovo system after October 24, 2014 with a flyer in the box. Your system would have been downgraded to Windows 7 with an option to upgrade to Windows 8.1/10 Pro".